# Avoiding rounding errors in a matrix calculation

Tags: java, numerical

I have the following very simple code that is supposed to iteratively change the values of a matrix (finalvals)until the row sums and column sums approach certain values (given by b1 and c) -

```
  double[] rowsums = new double[3];
    double[] colsums = new double[3];
    Double[][] finalvals = {
        {10320289.32d,15531663.71d,513718885.9d},
            {5741307.806d,19279894.22d,254573082.9d},
            {216919827.7d,229857986.8d,8769234962d}
    };
    Double[] b1 = {544169638d,273919997d,9217088452d};
    Double[] c = {232981430d,264669549d,9537527108d};
    for(int k = 0;k<1000;k++){
        for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<3;j++){
                rowsums[i] = rowsums[i] + finalvals[i][j];
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<3;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j<3;j++) {
                finalvals[i][j] = b1[i] * finalvals[i][j] / rowsums[i];
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<3;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j<3;j++) {
                colsums[j] = colsums[j] + finalvals[i][j];
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<3;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j<3;j++) {
                finalvals[i][j] = c[j] * finalvals[i][j] / colsums[j];
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++) {
        for(int j = 0;j<3;j++) {
            System.out.print(finalvals[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

However, the due to numerical leaks, the values of finalvals just become all zeros after a thousand iterations. Is there any way to plug these leaks?
Edit: A description of the algorithm - we want the matrix rows to sum to the arrays b1 and matrix columns to sum to array c. So, first distribute the first value of b1 among the first three rows of the matrix in proportion of the existing values and similarly for the other two rows. Then we do the same using the columns and the array c. We do this iteratively many times and we should finally get a matrix whose rows and columns sum appropriately.

Comment: If you need greater precision, use a [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: It won't make any difference to the calculations, but why on earth are you declaring some of those variables to be `Double` arrays instead of `double`? It will generate a huge amount of garbage due to autoboxing. (The "leaks" are probably due to ill-conditioning of the matrix; your code is not "very simple" and I don't know at first glance what matrix calculation you are trying to implement. It would help if you explained more.)

Comment: I've added an edit with a description of the algorithm. I've tried Doubles, double, floats, Floats and the problem remains. Let me try BigDecimal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've not heard the term *numerical leaks* before. Do you mean *rounding errors*.

Comment: @Quirliom: Using BigDecimal will almost certainly not help. Either you limit its precision and encounter the same problem, or you run into an OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: @Raedwald: Yes, rounding errors. The first few values in the matrix are small and they get successively rounded down through the iterations it seems.

Comment: @Michael: Your absolutely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. The reason was actually not rounding errors at all, but my code was wrong. I should have been setting the rowsums and colsums to zero after every iteration of the k loop. Thanks for every ones help.

Answer (score 1):

If your algorithm gives excessive rounding errors,  the solution should be to find a better algorithm, rather than to use higher precision numerics. This looks like a classic linear programming or simultaneous equation problem, for which there are tried and tested algorithms that work well. You need to sit down and study a bit on *numerical methods*.

Comment: I'm in a bit of a time crunch. This project is due soon. Can you please recommend an algorithm that does what I'm doing here (ensuring that the rows and columns of a matrix sum to certain values and that they remain as close as possible to their starting values). I've already tried constrained quadratic programming with both java (Joptimizer) and R and I get all kinds of singular matrix problems.